# Adding array of dates to object property

Tags: javascript

I got a array of days like this `date = [22,25,30]`.

i can pass the date for each item like below which works fine.

But i wanted to pass the date dynamically to the `this.highlightDays` instead of doing it one by one.

How can i do it ?  Please help

```
this.highlightDays = [
      {date: moment().date(22).valueOf()},
      {date: moment().date(25).valueOf()},
      {date: moment().date(30).valueOf()}
   ];
```

Comment: Do some research on [mapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Try `Array.prototype.map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const dates = [22, 25, 30];

this.highlightDays = dates.map((date) => ({
    date: moment().date(date).valueOf(),
}));

console.log(this.highlightDays);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```